# Differentiate null and empty in Postgres JOIN query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, postgresql-9.4

If I have tables like this:

```
t1:
 id | name 
----+------
  1 | a
  2 | b
  3 | c
  4 | d

t2:
 id | value 
----+-------
 10 | xxx
 20 | yyy
 30 | zzz

t_join:
 t1_id | t2_id 
-------+-------
     1 |    10
     2 |    20
     3 |    30
```

A SELECT query for t1.id=1 looks like:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.value FROM t1, t2,t_join WHERE t1.id=t_join.t1_id AND t2.id=t_join.t2_id AND t1.id=1;
```

And of course returns:

```
id | name | value 
----+------+-------
  1 | a    | xxx
```

If I do the same thing with `id=4`, I get nothing.

```
 SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.value FROM t1, t2,t_join WHERE t1.id=t_join.t1_id AND t2.id=t_join.t2_id AND t1.id=4;
 id | name | value 
----+------+-------
(0 rows)
```

And, if I do the same thing with a nonsense `id=1234132`, I also get nothing.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.value FROM t1, t2,t_join WHERE t1.id=t_join.t1_id AND t2.id=t_join.t2_id AND t1.id=1234132;
 id | name | value 
----+------+-------
(0 rows)
```

Is there a way I can differentiate between having an empty result (`id=4`) vs something that's null (`id=1234132`)? I guess I want verification that the id I'm checking exists without a separate query. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try the `OUTER JOIN` with table t1? which will return all the records in t1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a `left join`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.value
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
     t_join
     ON t1.id = t_join.t1_id LEFT JOIN
     t2 
     ON t2.id = t_join.t2_id 
WHERE t1.id = 1;
```

If `t.id` is not found, you'll get no rows.  If there are no matches in `t2`, then you'll get a `NULL` value.

Also, a simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always*, *always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.value FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t_join ON t1.id = t_join.t1_id LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t_join.t2_id WHERE t1.id = 1;`  (The second Left Join).

Also, are you recommending never to do the `JOIN` via `WHERE` clause as I did in the original question?

Comment: @Newtang . . . Commas in the `FROM` clause have been obsolete for over 20 years.

Comment: I understood the `FROM` comment, thanks. I was asking about the proper explicit `JOIN` part.